# how to linq to sql query for getting records of two columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to get data from both tables but it shows syntax error on `.ToList()` that is type mismatch.

Here is my code

```
List<activity> ObjActivitys = new List<activity>();

ObjActivitys = (from cn in _Context.activities
                join ac in _Context.activity_event on cn.id equals ac.activity_id
                where cn.lead_id == id 
                select new { cn, ac }).ToList();
```

kindly help me.

Comment: Why don't you add a navigation property from activity to event and just select your activities instead?

Comment: can it be solved without navigation property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select the Object type then:

If your `activity` looks like this:

```
public class activity
{
public activity Your_Prop1  {get;set;}
public activity_event Your_Prop2  {get;set;}

}
```

Then you can set `Your_Prop1` and `Your_Prop2`  in the select statement

```
List<activity> ObjActivitys = new List<activity>();

ObjActivitys = (from cn in _Context.activities
                join ac in _Context.activity_event on cn.id equals ac.activity_id
                where cn.lead_id == id 
                select new activity{ Your_Prop1 = cn, Your_Prop2 = ac }).ToList();
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you have a one-to-many relation between acitivty and activity_event table - then the Model should look something like this:

```
public class activity
{
public int id {get;set;}
//other properties

//
public virtual ICollection<acitivity_event> activity_events { get; set; }

}
```

So when you select an activity:

```
var myObj = dbContext.acitivty.First(s => s.id == 1);
```

you should be able to access the acitivty_events like this:

```
var thisActivityEvents = myObj.acitivty_events.ToList();
```

Comment: dawood bhai, activity class doesn't have property of activity event, both tables are different ?

Comment: So then create a DTO, if you want to select both things you need a DTO, or extend the Activity class

Comment: i have DO's of every table .

Comment: The thing is that i don't see why you are doing the inner join - If you select the activity by ID then you have a list of activity_events inside that object - because to me it seems like a 1-many relation between activity and acitivty_events, so in EF you don't need the Inner join

Comment: @NomanAhmad you can have more than one DTO / table you can have 10 DTO's DTO depends on the data you need. Not the DB schema and see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `List ObjActivitys = new List<activity>()` command

and use only:

```
 List<object>  objActivitys = (from cn in _Context.activities
                    join ac in _Context.activity_event on cn.id equals ac.activity_id
                    where cn.lead_id == id 
                    select new { cn,ac }).ToList();
```

Your linq query returns a list of anonymous type which you try to assign to a list of activity variable. This is why you get the type mismatch error.

You can than pass objActivitys to any other function. If you want to access the cn and ac properties , you can do something like this:

```
foreach(object activity in objActivitys)
{
   dynamic d = activity;
   // do something with  d.cn
   // do something with d.ac
}
```

Comment: i cant remove because i am returning the list of objects in the next step which cant take var.
return HelperConversion.MapActivityToDO(ObjActivitys);

Comment: I updated my answer. The type of objActitivies is List<object> which you can pass to you MapActivityToDO function

Comment: still giving same error ,type miss match and also mapper giving error.

Comment: You need to change you mapper method to accept List<object> instead of List<activity>

Comment: its the only method who's requirements are like this , i have others in same mapper which doesn't need this. so what should i suppose to do ?